# Reverse for 'task' not found. 'task' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django

in task_list.html {{task.title}} works fine but 'task' in href few lines below doesn't work. It shows the error "NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'task' not found. 'task' is not a valid view function or pattern name." for the a tag in 2nd table row in task_list.html

task_list.html:

```
 <h1>My To Do List</h1>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    {% for task in tasks %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{task.title}}</td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'task' task.title %}">View</a></td>
    </tr>
    {% empty %}
        <h3> No items in list</h3 >

    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import TaskList, TaskDetail

urlpatterns = [
    path('', TaskList.as_view(), name='tasks'),
    path('task/<int:pk>', TaskDetail.as_view(), name='tasks'),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from .models import Task

class TaskList(ListView):
    model = Task
    context_object_name = 'tasks'


class TaskDetail(DetailView):
    model = Task
    context_object_name = 'task'
    template_name = 'base/task.html'
```

Comment: Your url is named `tasks` with an `s` in the end _not_ `task`. Also it expects an _integer_ being the _pk_ of the object not a string, hence you need to write `{% url 'tasks' task.pk %}` instead of `{% url 'task' task.title %}`

Answer (score 1):

please try below code, i think need pk but you passed title

```
<h1>My To Do List</h1>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    {% for task in tasks %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{task.title}}</td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'task' task.pk %}">View</a></td>
    </tr>
    {% empty %}
        <h3> No items in list</h3 >

    {% endfor %}
</table>
```